# How to switch off DocFX in visual studio in debug mode while active in release mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docfx

I added DocFX to visual studio to generate web documents for my C# code. However, for every compilation it creates new documents which takes long time. Is there a way to switch it off in visual studio when I don't need it?

I know it is possible to uninstall/install it but this is the last resort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit the .csproj and add this line

```
<BuildDocFx Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Debug' ">false</BuildDocFx>
```

to the first `<PropertyGroup>` to disable docfx during debug builds

Comment: Works well on WPF project .Net 4.0 Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Also works well with Visual Studio 2019 with .Net Core 2.x.